# Rema more meikel than mechaber in bb"ch?

Tags: meat-and-milk, shulchan-aruch, machlokes, rama

Is Rema more lenient than [mechaber](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1693) anywhere in the laws of milk and meat? Usually, it seems, he is stricter.

Comment: Rema is more meikel than the mechaber in the case of fish and milk. The rema says that you can eat them together; the mechaber forbids it.

Comment: @AniYodea Does that have anything to do with the laws of Milk and Meat?

Comment: @doubleaa it is discussed by the Beis Yosef and shach and taz in Siman pei zayin. (The question was where in hilchos basar bchalav, not necessarily about milk and meat.)

Answer (score 3):

In siman 89 the Mechaber says waiting six hours between meat and milk is the letter of the law, the Ramma says it is a custom.

Comment: How is this a kula? Accd to the Rama, if my meal lasts 7 hours and I only at meat in the first few minutes, I still can't eat milk! Accd to the Mechaber though that would be fine.

Comment: @Double six hours has nothing to do with bracha achrona just like bracha achrona has nothing to do with six hours. So if someone finishes the meat at one and makes bracha achrona at seven, he can eat milk immediately according to both opinions in the Ramma

Comment: I agree. But if he finishes meat at 1 and meal at 8, then he can have ice cream for dessert at 7  only if he's a Mechaber-nick.

Comment: @Double the assumption is that under normal circumstances the six hours of the Ramma is a chumra compared to the finish and bench opinion. In fact the trumas hadeshen in his gloss on the Aruch, as brought in the taz says the tznuin wait six hours. This is a term reserved for people ergo are machmir.

Comment: Exactly my point. The Mechaber takes a side and goes with it all the way, lekula and lechumra. The Rama on the other hand has to be machmir both ways. This case is just another classic case of the Rama being machmir in BBCh and hence doesn't answer the question. As he himself would say "יש **להחמיר**"

Comment: @Double but the one hour opinion is not referred to as chumra in the poskim. Apparently none were worried enough about your scenario to even mention it. They only call six hours a chumra.